# How to copy 2 rows at the time?

Tags: matlab, matrix

**General idea**
There is a MxN  matrix from which the rows must be copied to another matrix 2 rows at the time>

**Example>**

```
matrix =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
```

then for copying the contents to another matrix

```
for k=1:size(matrix,1)
        eval(['V' '=matrix(k,:)'])
end
```

But how can copy 2 rows at the time using the permutations without repetition method? The idea is generate a temporal matrix in which apply some condition starting for the 1st and 2nd row until the last one, depending  on the size of the matrix provided by the user (so isn't the same size always). For the 1st matrix extracted it would be:

```
NewMatrix= [V1; V2]
    condition
end
```

**Trouble**
Is in the way it should be iterated/constructed(I guess so?) the NewMatrix element; by hand this would be:

```
 NewMatrix= [V1; V2]
 NewMatrix= [V1; V3]
 NewMatrix= [V1; V4]
 NewMatrix= [V1; V5]
```

Once this is done keeps with the next permutation

```
 NewMatrix= [V2; V1]
 NewMatrix= [V2; V3]
 NewMatrix= [V2; V4]
 NewMatrix= [V2; V5]
```

and so on...but how can this be generalized to a MxN matrix? to avoid adjust the code each time the user gives a matrix of different size?

Comment: Don’t use `eval`, it is not necessary there and will just slow down your code. Did you try adding a second `for` loop to that code?

Comment: @CrisLuengo let me check it...

Comment: I did remove the eval part, but it only saves the last row of the initial matrix:                                                         for k=1:size(matrix,1)
        V=matriz(x,:)
end

Comment: Yes, it does just like it did before with the eval. Your question is how to copy two rows at the time, you intend to do something with each pair within the door loop, no? What is it that you need?

Comment: It is supposed that the whole matrix must be tested if is linearly dependent/independent (linear algebra) that part is covered but when it is dependent it must be check if every vector its LD/LI between (thus when it is independent this 2 vectors generate a subspace). That the idea of extract 2 vectors make a new matrix and apply a condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can extract pairs of rows using array indexing and generate the permutations using nested loops:

```
matrix = magic(5);

for jj = 1:size(matrix,1)-1
    % The inner loop start index depends on the outer loop index to
    % avoid duplications.
    for kk = jj+1:size(matrix,1)
        NewMatrix = matrix([jj,kk],:)
        % Do something with NewMatrix
    end
end
```